# Usage of the account part of a derivation path to generate Ethereum addresses

Tags: wallets

[I recently read](https://medium.com/bitcraft/so-you-want-to-build-an-ethereum-hd-wallet-cb2b7d7e4998) that Ethereum doesn't use the part of the BIP44 derivation path dedicated to accounts. What happens if I still use it?

I just tried generating addresses under this path `m/44'/60'/1'/0/n`, opened MyCrypto with my Trezor and I can access such derivation path. Also, I can see and send funds from these addresses.

Should I worry about some future consequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I recently read that Ethereum doesn't use the part of the BIP44 derivation path dedicated to accounts.

Ledger Live uses the account section of the BIP44 derivation path. No one else does, afaik.

> I just tried generating addresses under this path m/44'/60'/1'/0/n, opened MyCrypto with my Trezor and I can access such derivation path. Also, I can see and send funds from these addresses.

The part of `m/44'/60'/1'/0/` that is the `account` is this bit => `/1'`

What MyCrypto does is increment the `address` portion of a derivation path to generate the keypairs that are shown on the website. Changing the `account` section just means that you're changing the base derivation path that is used. The `address` section is still what is being incremented on MyCrypto. As long as the derivation path that you use is valid, it'll still be processed the same way.